# Tab bar doesn't show all items - Xcode

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am building an application using Xcode and I am facing a problem with the tab bar. Sometimes when I run the application it works well and shows up all the items included in the tab bar.

[Tab bar shows all items - Image](http://img01.arabsh.com/uploads/image/2015/04/25/0c3e464963f705.png)
And sometimes in somehow it shows up only one item.

[Tab bar shows only one item - Image](http://img01.arabsh.com/uploads/image/2015/04/25/0c3e464963f704.png)
I don't know what is the problem and I couldn't fix it since it works fine but not always !

Comment: You are using only TabBar not TabBatrController, Right?

Comment: No, I am using a TabBarController.

Comment: Code... how are we supposed to help without any code you wrote to create the tabbar!?

Comment: I've created the tabbar without writing any code ..